# How can I check an image file exists in pug?

Tags: node.js, pug

I have some pug markup for images.

```
each player in players          
  - let src = "/images/" + player.playerName + ".png"
  img.image(src=src)
  br
```

What I would like to do is have a default image displayed when files don't exist. Like for example:

```
each player in players          
  - let src = "/images/" + player.playerName + ".png"
  - src = exists(src) ? src : "images/default.png"
  img.image(src=src)
  br
```

The solutions I've found so far would involve making changes on the server before passing the object to the pug markup. Ideally I'd like to do it here in pug, I think it would be cleaner. Is there a way I can do it in my view?

Comment: Are you trying to do this only at compile time?

Comment: I would prefer at compile time, but I wouldn't mind using an onError handler if it means I can do it through pug

Comment: If you are compiling on the fly, then you may be able to use a filter to check if the image exists then revert to the default.That's the only other solution I can see being possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do that as pug is only a template language. You can use Javascript on the client to switch out non-existent images using `image.onerror` but other than that you'll need to use either server side or client side processing to figure it out.